# RealityKit – Displaying .reality file with SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, arkit, realitykit

Im trying to display reality file using ARView but when the model is opened it is super small and the gestures are not working. Can someone please point me out what I am doing wrong?
The reality file should be displayed without using the phone camera.

```
struct AugmentedRealityView: UIViewRepresentable {

var name: String
var url: URL

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ARView {
    let arView = ARView(frame: .zero)
    arView.cameraMode = .nonAR
    
    load(url: url, name: name) {
        result in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let model):
            let anchor = AnchorEntity()
            arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
            
            let parentEntity = ModelEntity()
            parentEntity.addChild(model)

            // Handle the gestures for rotation and scale
            let entityBounds = model.visualBounds(relativeTo: parentEntity)
            parentEntity.collision = CollisionComponent(shapes: [ShapeResource.generateBox(size: entityBounds.extents).offsetBy(translation: entityBounds.center)])
            arView.installGestures(.all, for: parentEntity)
            anchor.addChild(parentEntity)
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print("\nError: \(error)")
        }
    }

    return arView
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: ARView, context: Context) { }

private func load(url: URL, name: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<Entity, Error>) -> ()) {
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    cancellable = ModelEntity.loadAsync(contentsOf: url, withName: name)
        .sink(
            receiveCompletion: { loadCompletion in
                
                if case let .failure(error) = loadCompletion {
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
                }
                cancellable?.cancel()
            },
            receiveValue: { model in
                
                completionHandler(.success(model))
            })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to set an appropriate scale for your model:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity()

anchor.addChild(model)
anchor.scale = [50, 50, 50]   
arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
```

If you want to see how this code may look like and where is its place in `receiveValue` block of `loadModelAsync()` method, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752649/realitykit-asynchronous-model-loading-doesnt-work/62755956#62755956).