# Using Strings as name in object calls

Tags: swift, string, types, realitykit

I am reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752649/realitykit-asynchronous-model-loading-doesnt-work) on async `ModelEntity` loading, and the code is clear. What I fail to understand is how I can substitute the model call for `Entity.loadModelAsync(named: "Glasses.usdz")` with my chosen model through a `[String]` or `String` , such as when making a new function with the model name in the parameters, like

```
Entity.loadModelAsync(named: models.randomElement())
```

This results in the warning `Cast from 'String' to unrelated type 'ModelEntity' always fails`

I was expecting a simple substitution for what looks like a `String` to not be a problem, but I am being confronted with errors about "unrelated data types" when my personal logic says that something "in quotes" should be possibly called through a `String` , e.g. data I am storing inside a `[String]`.

My `models` array is an array of `String` names of models I have loaded inside my app bundle. I would like to use any model's name as the input string in the call to `Entity.loadModelAsync(named:)` through the `.randomElement()` function of the array.

```
let models = ["Robot.usdz", "Airplane.usdz", "Beachball.usdz"]
```

or

```
let models = ["customModel1", "customModel2", "customModel3"]
```

Why is Swift so finicky about an object's name property?

Comment: Is `models` an array of `String`? Please post some more code, we can't [reproduce your example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have amended my question. I'm playing around with this for now, so I don't have a lot of code to begin with as it's taken from the response I linked to.